# How to skip specific refactoring commands in liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

We have several liquibase scripts containing lots of custom sql queries we don't want to execute automatically.
We would like to know if a configuration exists that skips specific refactoring commands, as `<sql>` or `<dropTable>`. It would be helpfull to exclude these commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to control which changeSets execute at runtime using "[contexts](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html)". Tag the changeSets you want to run conditionally with helpful context names,  and then when you run liquibase you can pass in the list of contexts you want executed.